# ASP.NET Core: Assign port in runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to create a MVC6 application which would automatically bind to an available port on it's host. You could for example run the same application on one host and second instance would choose different port than the first one.

To do this, I need to assign port in the runtime.

Is it possible? If so how? All I could find was to setup port in the config file or environment variables.

Comment: I assume you're using Kestrel? https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/758

Comment: How would you tell the client what port they should connect to?

Comment: Server would update the registry with its port and clients would be asking registry for the server address.